# how to solve Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter

I am doing an app that has login, bottomNavigator and also pagination. I use SharedPreferences to store my token but it gives an error about `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`.

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share your debug console log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your model class has some issue like it requires an integer and it is getting the String so the error has occured, just check your model class.

Comment: thank you for your reply, my model class is correct, but still have that error

Comment: So when you save the token have you checked if it is empty or null, if so let me know

Comment: become null, before I add pagination and bottom navigation, it can work, after I add it it become [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
#0      saveToken (package:screens/login.dart:26:31)

Comment: I did not get your comment, are you saying API gets triggered you get a token but later it becomes null or you are getting the null token

Comment: I get the token after I press login, then I use SharedPreferences to store my token, because I need to use that token to do other http request. But when I do this I get the error, so the token become null and cannot use the token in other place

Comment: what I think is when you save the token(i.e response.body) that's ok, but when you retrieve it you have to decode it and then pass it to a model. so you get an object from which you can access it. And one more thing when you make a login request what return response you are getting(can you post the JSON after login ) from it let me know. This is the preferred way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208407/discussion-between-qing-and-sagar-acharya).